# zlib inflate method not working as expected

Tags: c++, c, zlib

This is the code being used to inflate:

```
z_ret = inflate(&oStream, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);
```

`z_ret` returns `Z_DATA_ERROR` every time except for the first time in incoming stream

Comment: Looking in the zlib.h file, `-3` is `Z_DATA_ERROR`, so maybe there's a data error.

Comment: data error means ?? Is the data incoming is not valid ?

Comment: Does YOUR code return -3 or is it ZLIB's return code? Please clarify.

Comment: @Salsa: well-spotted there... I had focussed on `z_ret` equaling -3, but looking at the code you're right, it's unclear what `inflate` actually returns.

Comment: @Salsa ... i tried to see return value using if (z_ret = Z_DATA_ERROR) in my code . It is going inside this if condition .That means inflate method is returning Z_DATA_ERROR.

Comment: THe reason is shown as Z_DATA_ERROR incorrect header check. What could be the cause for this issue ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html) webpage:

> `Z_DATA_ERROR` indicates that `inflate()` detected an error in the zlib compressed data format, which means that either the data is not a zlib stream to begin with, or that the data was corrupted somewhere along the way since it was compressed.

Alternatively, it's possible that the data was compressed with a specific deflate dictionary, which zlib will need in order to inflate. If this is the case, the according to the link I mentioned:

> ... we have no idea what the dictionary is, so the `Z_NEED_DICT` indication is converted to a `Z_DATA_ERROR`.

I've not used zlib much myself, but this hints that you either have corrupt data, or not enough information to be able to decompress.

---

**Edit**: Having looked at Salsa's comment, and examining your code more, it's not clear that this is the actual issue. You don't state what value `z_ret` has when `inflate` fails.

Comment: inflate method is returning Z_DATA_ERROR.

Comment: which link you are talking about

Comment: @user3136124: The link to the zlib webpage.